# What is the difference between SSL pinning (embedded in host) and normal certificates (presented by server)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-pinning

I'm not quite understanding the necessity of certificate pinning in SSL connection establishment (to avoid Man in the Middle attacks).

SSL cert pinning requires embedding original server certificate in the host to verify with the one presented by server. what is the difference between the server certificate embedded in the host and the one presented by server to be validated by client?

What is that I am missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> what is the difference between the server certificate embedded in the host and the one presented by server to be validated by client?

There should be none and that's exactly the point of certificate pinning.

Without certificate pinning an application commonly accepts any certificate which matches the requested hostname and is issued by a locally trusted CA (certificate authority). Given that there are usually more than 100 CA in the local trust store it is sufficient that one of these got successfully attacked as in [the case of DigiNotar](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2011/aug/30/faked-web-certificate-iran-dissidents) in 2011. Thus it makes sense to limit the certificate you accept to a specific one, i.e. pinning.

Besides the certificate pinning by comparing the certificate received with a locally stored certificate there are other ways of pinning: for example one might just check against a fingerprint (hash) and not the full certificate. In case the certificate can expire it might be more useful to check only the public key and not the whole certificate because the public key is often kept on certificate renewal. Or one might pin to a specific CA which one considers trusted to issue certificates for this domain.

Note that to understand pinning you might need to understand how the authentication of the server works. One part of this is that the server certificate is validated (hostname, expiration, trust chain ...). But this is not enough since the certificate itself is public, i.e. everybody can get it and could send it inside the TLS handshake. Thus the other major part of the authentication is that the server proves that it is the owner of the certificate. This is done by signing some data using the private key matching the certificate. Since only the owner of the certificate should have the private key this proves ownership. Because of this anybody could embed the servers certificate for pinning but only the server itself can prove ownership of the certificate.

Answer (score 2):

### What is SSL pinning

Applications are configured to trust a select few certificates or certificate authority (CA), instead of the default behaviour: to trust all CAs that are pre-configured on the device/ machine. SSL pinning is not ***required***.

### Why use SSL Pinning (Why not to)

In many cases, the certificate returned by a server could be tampered as long as any Root (or intermediate root) CA was compromised (happens very rarely). Threat actors could use this compromised CA to generate a certificate for your website, and show visitors their website instead. This is bad. SSL pinning was designed to prevent this in some cases, but there are better ways (IMHO).

Having said that, I don' t know any *website* which uses SSL pinning so SSL pinning seems primarily discussed for mobile apps. It seems like SSL pinning **only** works when you can trust the source of the application (e.g. App Store, Play Store) Why? Because if you have to visit a website to get the cert, by then its too late (you might have already used a dodgy cert and accessed the fake website or was MITM'd). Therefore, it seems like the benefits Steffen mentioned are not so compelling, especially when there are better solutions already:

### Better solution

I'm not sure if *any-CA-compromise* is a threat vector, even for banks. Instead, banks and other security conscious organisations will pick their CA wisely, and also configure a [CAA record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Certification_Authority_Authorization).

- By using a CAA DNS record, they can restrict clients (e.g. browsers, mobile apps) to trust only certain certificates when accessing their specific website.
- They pick the CA and create a cert only from this CA
- They will have a backup plan for if a CA is compromised. Don't want to go into that here, but the backup plan for CAA records is IMHO much better than that of SSL pinning.

For example, Monzo.com (I used [whatsmydns](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CAA/monzo.com) to find this) has a CAA record which restricts certificates to only 4 CAs (digicert, amazon, comodoca, buypass):

```
0 iodef "mailto:security@monzo.com"
0 issue "amazon.com"
0 issue "buypass.com"
0 issue "comodoca.com"
0 issue "digicert.com"
0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
0 issuewild "amazon.com"
0 issuewild "comodoca.com"
0 issuewild "digicert.com"
0 issuewild "letsencrypt.org"
```

These are popular CAs which people trust, we **hope** they don't let us down. If they do, the whole internet would be a free for all. The only way to prevent this is to be your own CA/ use self-signed certificates.

### Summary

I don't see how SSL pinning will become ubiquitous, especially since it adds more overhead (maintenance regarding ssl expiry, or trusting one CA anyway - SPoF, or emulating what a CAA record does but with additional code/ maintenance burden). It also only supports your pre-installed applications, not websites.